# How to hide a parent Stack Navigator Header only in certain screens in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

As per title, I would like to hide the header of a parent stack navigator **from** a children component, this is because there are certain screens where I would like to keep the parent header and some screens where I would not.

I'm aware that one could simply set the header property to null in the parent Stack Navigator but is there any way I could change that property from a children component, during runtime?

Here's the hierarchy of the navigators:

```
ParentStackNavigator
|
|__TabNavigator
   |__Other Screen
   |__MainScreen (Stack Navigator)
      |
      |__ScreenWithHeader
      |__ScreenWithoutHeader
```

The challenge is to hide the header in ParentStackNavigator when I'm in ScreenWithoutHeader but not when I'm in ScreenWithHeader. One solution that I could think of is to wrap the entire thing with a context but I'm hopeful that there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide header in a stack-navigator you must do this:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
```

And if you want to hide heade in one screen only you have to do like this:

```
<Stack.Screen name={screens.Home} component={Home} options={{headerShown: false}} />
```

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked.